# Java Script- Why doesn't this switch case statement work?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm new to JS and I'm trying to do an assignment on codewars. It's supposed to be a rock,paper, scissors game and to return which player won or if there was a draw. I tried using switch case for this solution, however in some cases it returns the wrong answer. I know it can be solved using the if statement, however I am curious why my solution does not work. Could someone explain? Thank You in advance :)

Here is what I tried:

```
let rps = (p1, p2) => {
  switch (p1,p2){
  case "scissors" && "paper":
    return "Player 1 won!";
      break;
  case "scissors"&& "rock":
    return "Player 2 won!";
       break;
  case "scissors"&& "scissors":
    return "Draw!";
       break;
  case "paper"&& "paper":
    return "Draw!";
       break;
  case "paper"&& "scissors":
    return "Player 2 won!";
       break;
  case "paper"&& "rock":
    return "Player 1 won!";
       break;
  case "rock"&& "rock":
    return "Draw";
       break;
  case "rock"&& "paper":
    return "Player 2 won!";
       break;
  case "rock" && "scissors":
    return "Player 1 won!";
       break;
}
};
```

Comment: because switch is only one value match, it is not two

Comment: You should probably look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). `switch` takes a _single_ expression, and then matches _single_ case values against it. You can't use conditions like you're doing. You should really be using `if` statements instead. Side note: since you're returning in each case you don't need those `break` statements.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `if` statements, not a `switch`.  In this case what you have is a bunch of cases for the same value (the boolean `true`) and you're testing that value against `p2` and *only* `p2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch only supports one value. To use it as a switch you would need to concatenate the strings.

```
switch (p1 + p2){
  case "scissorspaper":
    return "Player 1 won!";
  case "scissorsrock":
    return "Player 2 won!";
  case "scissorsscissors":
    return "Draw!";
```

other option is a nested switch

```
switch (p1){
  case "scissors":
    switch (p2){
      case "paper":
        return "Player 1 won!";
      case "rock":
        return "Player 2 won!";
      case "scissors":
        return "Draw!";
  case "paper":
    ....
```

Answer (score 2):

A `switch` statement only takes one expression. Note that `p1,p2` applies the comma operator, which will result in the value of `p2`. Your `case` expressions only check one expression. Also here the `&&` operator will evaluate to one of both operands.

There are a few things you can do to reduce the code repetition here:

- The three words have distinct first letters, so you could make the logic only look at first letters
- If you place those distinct letters in a string, then you can make it that if two letters are consecutive, that means the first player won.

So, you can do this:

```
const rps = (p1, p2) => {
  if (p1 === p2) return "Draw!";
  if ("sprs".includes(p1[0] + p2[0])) return "Player 1 won!";
  return "Player 2 won!";
}
```

Using the same logic, but putting it in one expression:

```
const rps = (p1, p2) =>
   p1 === p2 ? "Draw!" : `Player ${2-"sprs".includes(p1[0] + p2[0])} won!`;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not how **switch** works. Switch looks for exact value match to the given statement.

You want to use either **if** like so:

```
const response = (p1, p2) => {
  if (p1 === "scissors" && p2 === "paper") {
    return "Player 1 won!";
  }

  // more ifs...
}
```

Or, if you insist of using switch, compare for example `string` value of the combination, like so:

```
const response = (p1, p2) => {
  const combination = `${p1}:${p2}`;
  switch (combination) {
    case "scissors:paper":
      return "Player 1 won!";

    // ...more cases...
  }
}
```

Also, note that you don't need to break after return. Return statements exits your function immediately.

Answer (score 0):

A switch checks a single condition. You can swap the check, however, and test for true given a check of the two arguments in each case.

Note, you should also use a plain function or `const` instead of `let`, unless you want to reassign `rps` later in the same scope. Also, the `return` means you don't need a `break` after each `return`. And you don't have a default return (doh!). You can also group the outcomes, since the fall through outcomes all return and stop the case matching.

```
const rps = (p1, p2) => {
  switch (true) {
    case p1 === "scissors" && p2 === "scissors":
    case p1 === "paper" && p2 === "paper":
    case p1 === "rock" && p2 === "rock":
      return "Draw!";
    case p1 === "scissors" && p2 === "paper":
    case p1 === "paper" && p2 === "rock":
    case p1 === "rock" && p2 === "scissors":
      return "Player 1 won!";
    case p1 === "scissors" && p2 === "rock":
    case p1 === "paper" && p2 === "scissors":
    case p1 === "rock" && p2 === "paper":
      return "Player 2 won!";
  }

  return "Doh!"
};
```